# Lamp on ubuntu 14.04 .Only want localhost - how?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web, lamp

I want to setup a lamp stack to act as a testing area for my website. I only want it open to my computer on localhost - definitely not the internet. Is there a way to ensure this?

Thanks

Comment: Off topic for Stackoverflow, which is aimed at _programming_ questions. Please ask on http://www.serverfault.com and delete here.

Comment: i'll take a look at that forum. I'm new here so just getting used to what is available.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have to worry too much about this, but there is a solution to be sure that is only localhost.

You need to configure your Apache to listen only to your localhost address and port.

***The solution is a bit old, but I don't have Lamp installed on my computer so you have to try it and tell me if it works.***

This can be done by editing the file:  `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

You can do that with this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And replace the `Listen 80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341925)

Comment: thanks i'll give it a go and let you know how i get on.